# Resizing root partition that is in the middle of other partitions?

Tags: partitioning, uefi

I installed Ubuntu on /dev/nvme0n1p8. However, now the root partition is too small. I have some unallocated space at the end of the disk. Is there any way I could extend the Ubuntu root partition?

[image: Gparted]

Comment: This should help you : [Moving home partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)

Comment: If this were I, I would back up everything, then make a new ext4 partition in the unused space.  clone the / partition and paste it into the new partition. Delete the old / partition and expand the existing big partition into the hole. Adjust grub as necessary, expand the new / to fill all the space. Details left as exercise for the reader.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi thank you moving home partition sounds like the best option

Comment: If I was doing it I would fire up a gparted Live disc/USB and slide all the partitions to the right.  Then expand the RIGHT side of the current / parition to fill the space.  When done you will need to have a Live CD or USB of Boot Repair.  But you will be back in business.